# Angularjs: Why is $scope.variable in $watch not up-to-date?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I created a Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xt2Zsx5gjECsCYKrSKmM?p=preview) to illustrate the problem. Here is the main code:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
      <caption class="text-left" style="background-color: lightgray">
          Search: <input ng-model="searchString" style="width: 80px" />
          Filted count: {{filteredList.length}}
      </caption>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Sex</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="emp in filteredList = (data.employees | filter:searchString)">
        <td>{{emp.firstName}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{emp.sex}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

App.js:

```
$scope.searchString = '';
$scope.$watch('searchString', function(str) {
  console.log($scope.filteredList.length);
});
```

The problem is that the console.log of filteredList.length is always one loop behind (compared to html which is correct), that is, from previous filter. How can I fix it?

Comment: Say searchString changes, it's going to fire your watch expression based on that it's also going to cause a call to $apply/$digest to take care of updating any DOM elements that are bound.  When it goes to update the DOM elements it will rerun the expresssions and update the filterdList variable (but at this point it has already triggered the watch and it's too late).  I'd consider applying the assignment and filter function from within a controller function (perhaps within this watch) so you can do things synchronously.

Comment: Updated answer with implementation more like what shaunhusain suggests.  http://plnkr.co/AA25PkyCPOfSmgVyJ9mZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are logging `filteredList.length` as soon as `searchString` changes.  But, at at moment, `filteredList` has not yet been modified by the filter in `ngRepeat`.

One way to fix this would be to `$watch` `filteredList.length` instead:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
  return ($scope.filteredList || []).length;
...
```

**Update**
I really like shaunhusain's comment.  His suggestion is probably closer to what you really want to do.

```
$scope.searchString = '';
// Initialize filteredItems as a copy of data.employees
$scope.filteredItems = angular.copy($scope.data.employees);

// Watch your search string instead and apply filtering using $filter
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.searchString;
  }, 
  function(str) {
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.data.employees, {$: $scope.searchString}, false);
    console.log($scope.filteredItems.length);
  });
```

Then, your `ngRepeat` is simply:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="emp in filteredItems">
    <td>{{emp.firstName}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.lastName}}</td>
    <td>{{emp.sex}}</td>
  </tr>
```